# Atata: Unable to locate CheckBox elements

Tags: c#, automated-tests, ui-automation, atata

I receive an error when I use `[VerifyExists]` on a `CheckBox` element, although when I use the `XPath` that is generated via the framework i can find the element.

**Error message:**

```
Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to locate element: By.XPath: .//*[normalize-space(@id) = 'active-checker']/descendant-or-self::input[@type='checkbox']
```

**Implementation:**

```
[VerifyExists]
[FindById("isCommentRequred-checker")]
public CheckBox<_> RequestsWorklogCommentCheckBox { get; private set; }
```

**Manual search for element:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that it is because actual `<input type="checkbox">` is invisible (or has `opacity: 0`) on the page. Atata by default for most controls filters elements by visibility during control element search and leaves only visible elements.

Try to set `Visibility = Visibility.Any`:

```
[FindById("isCommentRequred-checker", Visibility = Visibility.Any)]
```

Often checkboxes and radio buttons are made invisible and other element renders it and receives clicks. Just inspect HTML and then try to click it with Atata or with pure WebDriver. If it throws exception, you will probably need to implement custom control for it to click for example `span.control-label` element.

Here is example of control for Kendo UI CheckBox: https://github.com/atata-framework/atata-kendoui/blob/master/src/Atata.KendoUI/KendoCheckBox%601.cs

Comment: Than you, Yevgeniy!

[VerifyExists]
        [FindById("active-checker", Visibility = Visibility.Any)]

Worked for me.

Comment: This works for a problem I was having with RadioButton as well, though ultimately I had to XPath to the label to get it.